How to convert daily ERA5 data to Monthly mean data in GEE
I want to convert daily max temperature data to monthly average from ERA5 daily data
I HAVE A CODE TO EXTRACT DAILY MAX TEMPERATURE DATA
Map.addLayer(bho, {}, "Bhopal");
Map.centerObject(bho);
           

var  temp2 = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR')
                   .select('temperature_2m_max')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-09-01', '2024-04-30'));

var temp2_list =  temp2.toList( temp2.size());

print(temp2_list);

var study_area =  temp2_list.map(function(img){
  
  var date = ee.Date(ee.Image(img).get('system:time_start')).format().slice(0, 10);
  img = ee.Image(img).subtract(273.15);
  
  var value_temp = ee.Image(img)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), bho)
    .get('temperature_2m_max');
  
  return [date, value_temp];
  
});

var vis2mt = {
  min: -20,
  max: -10,
  palette: [
    '#000080', '#0000D9', '#4000FF', '#8000FF', '#0080FF', '#00FFFF', '#00FF80',
    '#80FF00', '#DAFF00', '#FFFF00', '#FFF500', '#FFDA00', '#FFB000', '#FFA400',
    '#FF4F00', '#FF2500', '#FF0A00', '#FF00FF'
  ]
};

var image = ee.Image( temp2_list.get(0))
  .subtract(273.15)
  .clip(bho);
print(image);

Map.addLayer(image, vis2mt);

print(study_area);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(study_area.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list

  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': el.get(0),
    'value_temp': el.get(1),
  });
}));

print(myFeatures);

Export.table(myFeatures, 'dailytempbho', {fileFormat: 'CSV'});
print("Export dailytempbho", myFeatures.limit(5).getDownloadURL('csv'));

This is the code I have used to extract daily max temperature data ,I want to average the daily max values into monthly basis?
